# Selecting the rows with the N most recent unique values of a datetime

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres DB in which most of the tables have a column 'valid_time' indicating when the data in that row is intended to represent and an 'analysis_time' column, indicating when the estimate was made (this might be the same or a later time than the valid time in the case of a measurement or an earlier time in the case of a forecast). Typically there are multiple analysis times for each valid time, corresponding to different measurements (if you wait a bit, more data is available for a given time, so the analysis is better but the measurment is less prompt) and forecasts with different lead times.

I am using SQLalchemy to access this DB in Python.

What I would like to do is be able to pull out all rows with the most recent N unique datetimes of a specified column. For instance I might want the 3 most recent unique valid times, but this will typically be more than 3 rows, because there will be multiple analysis times for each of those 3 valid times.

I am new to relational databases. In a sense there are two parts to this question; how can this be achieved in bare SQL and then how to translate that to the SQLalchemy ORM?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to the first part of your question . . . how to do this in SQL:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by validtime desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= N;
```

This is using the `dense_rank()` window/analytic function.  This enumerates the time values, with ties given the same rank value.  The `where` clause simply chooses how many you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the SQLalchemy part, but as far as the SQL queries I would do it in two steps:

1. Get the times.  For example, something like.

   `SELECT DISTINCT valid_time FROM MyTable LIMIT 3 ORDER BY valid_time DESC;`
2. Get the rows with those times, using the previous step as a subquery:

   `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE valid_time IN (SELECT DISTINCT valid_time FROM MyTable LIMIT 3 ORDER BY valid_time DESC);`